# Taking integer and string input from GUI in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm looking for a library to take an integer and string input from a user in Python. Some Google searches point to using `Tkinter` and 'Tkinter Entry', but now how do I code it for integer and code another for string?

I'm trying to create a simple input box, take an integer as input and assign that integer to some variable.

Comment: Do you have an actual question? This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: most inputs work with text. Take text and convert it to integer - `int(text)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code provides examples using `tkinter` with an Entry widget to get the user input or alternatively using `tkinter.simpledialog` to display a window for the user to enter a value.

Here is a useful [guide](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) to using `tkinter`. There are many more out there for beginners like yourself

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring, askinteger
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror


def display_1():
    # .get is used to obtain the current value
    # of entry_1 widget (This is always a string)
    print(entry_1.get())

def display_2():
    num = entry_2.get()
    # Try convert a str to int
    # If unable eg. int('hello') or int('5.5')
    # then show an error.
    try:
       num = int(num)
    # ValueError is the type of error expected from this conversion
    except ValueError:
        #Display Error Window (Title, Prompt)
        showerror('Non-Int Error', 'Please enter an integer')
    else:
        print(num)

def display_3():
    # Ask String Window (Title, Prompt)
    # Returned value is a string
    ans = askstring('Enter String', 'Please enter any set of characters')
    # If the user clicks cancel, None is returned
    # .strip is used to ensure the user doesn't
    # enter only spaces ' '
    if ans is not None and ans.strip():
        print(ans)
    elif ans is not None:
        showerror('Invalid String', 'You must enter something')

def display_4():
    # Ask Integer Window (Title, Prompt)
    # Returned value is an int
    ans = askinteger('Enter Integer', 'Please enter an integer')
    # If the user clicks cancel, None is returned
    if ans is not None:
        print(ans)

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create the widgets
entry_1 = tk.Entry(root)
btn_1 = tk.Button(root, text = "Display Text", command = display_1)

entry_2 = tk.Entry(root)
btn_2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Display Integer", command = display_2)

btn_3 = tk.Button(root, text = "Enter String", command = display_3)
btn_4 = tk.Button(root, text = "Enter Integer", command = display_4)

# Grid is used to add the widgets to root
# Alternatives are Pack and Place
entry_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
btn_1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
entry_2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
btn_2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

btn_3.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
btn_4.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dear Steven, how can I save the answer of the user-input digits for instance? Suppose I want to save the results of the digits and use them in another place in my code. How is that done?

Comment: There is nothing special you have to do, just store it in a variable you can access from where you need it.

Comment: Thanks Steven, and how can i show the output of my code on GUI ?

Answer (score 1):

if you want an actual GUI, then tkinter is the simplest way, but if you only want simple raw input then `input()` works fine.

example:

```
test=input('prompt:') #take input
print(test*10) #print it ten times
```

`simpledialog` comes with python 3.x and has pop-ups that have an input box on them. but isn't as easy as `input()`